# error: cannot access zzbgl. class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, gmsmapview, gmsplace

I want to show location of places in my app.

I get compile error of **cannot access zzbgl**

This is my gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.whiteelephant:monthandyearpicker:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.tarun0.zxing-standalone:zxing-standalone:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.edwardvanraak:MaterialBarcodeScanner:0.0.6-ALPHA'
    implementation "ru.tinkoff.scrollingpagerindicator:scrollingpagerindicator:1.0.6"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

it shows compile error

> error: cannot access zzbgl
>
> class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

In my activity

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        this.location = location;

        this.googleMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( new LatLng( location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() ), 18 ) );

        this.googleMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions().position( new LatLng( location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() ) ).title( "You are Hear" ) );

        Marker myMarker = googleMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions().position( new LatLng( 0.0, 0.0 ) ) );
        myMarker.remove();

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        Log.d( "latitude", String.valueOf( latitude ) );
        Log.d( "longitude", String.valueOf( longitude ) );
    }
```

It show error on this line :

```
    this.googleMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions().position( new LatLng( location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() ) ).title( "You are Hear" ) );
```

Please help me.

How to solve this error.

Comment: It will be better if you add full stack trace

Comment: Might be you have not updated library with latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

> **Note:** Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.

Therefore, remove the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

And add the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to the following fixed it for me: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'